# CSS styling multiple ID's

Tags: css

instead of this:

```css
#1 span.error { color: #fff; }
#2  span.error { color: #fff; }
```

Is it better/quicker to use:

```css
#1 span.error, #2 span.error { color: #fff; }
```

Is there a way to shorten even more?

**I am accepting Ana's answer, but for me agam360 hit the target first.
Thank you all**

Comment: Why not use:
span.error {color:#fff;}?

Comment: just a note, id can't start with a number

Comment: @agam360 Same here now that u mention it... I need to rest a bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe it is better - you avoid redundancy and if you have this situation multiple times, it can significantly reduce the size of your CSS.

Even shorter would be to add the same class to the two ids. Something like:

```
<div id="#1" class="myclass">
  <span class="error">error text 1</span>
</div>
<div id="#2" class="myclass">
  <span class="error">error text 1</span>
</div>
```

and then you can write:

```
.myclass span.error {
  color: #fff;
}
```

*If you don't have any `span.error` elements outside the elements having ids `#1` and `#2`*, then you could compact this further to just `span.error { color: #fff; }`

*If, in addition to this, the elements having class `.error` are always `<span>` elements*, them it cam become `.error { color: #fff; }`

So how much you can compact things really depends on your HTML structure.

Comment: In *some* situations he could, but perhaps he also has `span.error` elements outside those two elements and he wants the `span.error` elements styled differently when they are inside either of those two elements having ids `#1` and `#2`.

Comment: @Ana It was "stupid" what I did... I do not have span.error outside those ids. :) ty

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the structure of your page.

`span.error { color: #fff; }` would shorten it more, or if the ancestor is required to  be in the rule and follows a pattern you could write something this `div[id*='pattern'] span.error`.
In this example the ancestor is a `div` that id contains the text "pattern". You can modify it to fit your needs.